# How to display array sent back from Ajax Request. Using Yii2

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, yii2

I have sent of an ajax request, it then will query the database and send back what I want. However I am stuck on actually displaying this when it is returned to my page.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('cases/ajax') ?>',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { firstcategory: firstcategory },
    success: function(data) {
        for (var key in data) {
            var value = data[key];
            alert(value);
            document.write(value);
        }   
    }
});
```

As you can see, I am trying to display the value but it is coming back with an array.

This is what is being sent back from ajax request:

```
Array
(
[0] => app\models\Subcategory Object
    (
        [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [subcategory_id] => 1
                [name] => ADJUDICATION ON BEHALF OF OR AGAINST AN INSOLVENT PARTY
                [parent_id] => 2
            )

        [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [subcategory_id] => 1
                [name] => ADJUDICATION ON BEHALF OF OR AGAINST AN INSOLVENT PARTY
                [parent_id] => 2
            )

        [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[1] => app\models\Subcategory Object
    (
        [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [subcategory_id] => 2
                [name] => THE EXISTENCE OF A CONTRACT
                [parent_id] => 3
            )

        [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [subcategory_id] => 2
                [name] => THE EXISTENCE OF A CONTRACT
                [parent_id] => 3
            )

        [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[2] => app\models\Subcategory Object
    (
        [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [subcategory_id] => 3
                [name] => THE MEANING OF CONSTRUCTION CONTRACT
                [parent_id] => 3
            )

        [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [subcategory_id] => 3
                [name] => THE MEANING OF CONSTRUCTION CONTRACT
                [parent_id] => 3
            )

        [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )
  )
```

Okay, now I want to display the data in just this section:

```
[subcategory_id] => 1
[name] => ADJUDICATION ON BEHALF OF OR AGAINST AN INSOLVENT PARTY
[parent_id] => 2
```

How do i achieve this in javascript when i receive the data back in the variable "data"?

Thanks for any help you can give me

---

**Edit**:

This is my controller:

```
public function actionAjax() {
    if(isset($_POST['firstcategory'])) {
        $firstcategory = $_POST['firstcategory'];
        $subcategory = Subcategory::find()->all();
    } else {
        $firstcategory = "Ajax failed";
    }

    print_r($subcategory);
    exit;

    return \yii\helpers\Json::encode($subcategory);
}
```

---

**Second edit**:

I receive this json

```
[
    {
        "subcategory_id": "1",
        "name": "ADJUDICATION ON BEHALF OF OR AGAINST AN INSOLVENT PARTY",
        "parent_id": "2"
    },
    {
        "subcategory_id": "2",
        "name": "THE EXISTENCE OF A CONTRACT",
        "parent_id": "3"
    },
    {
        "subcategory_id": "3",
        "name": "THE MEANING OF CONSTRUCTION CONTRACT",
        "parent_id": "3"
    },
    {
        "subcategory_id": "4",
        "name": "THE MEANING OF CONSTRUCTION OPERATIONS",
        "parent_id": "3"
    },
    {
        "subcategory_id": "5",
        "name": "EXCLUDED CONSTRUCTION OPERATIONS",
        "parent_id": "3"
    },
    {
        "subcategory_id": "6",
        "name": "EXCLUDED AGREEMENTS",
        "parent_id": "3"
    }
]
```

Now in my view I am trying to parse it but I'm unsure

```
success: function(data) {
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    document.write(obj.subcategory_id);
}
```

This isn't working?

Comment: Can you show your query?

Comment: i have edited my question for you, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

```
$subcategory = Subcategory::find()->all();
```

to

```
$subcategory = Subcategory::find()->asArray()->all();
```

this will give the resultset in array format and then you can pass it as json.

Then in your ajax success, parse the Json result.

```
var result = $.parseJSON(data);

for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
    alert(result[i].subcategory_id);
}
```

Comment: fantastic! now how would i display this in javascript when i receive it back as "data" in success part of my ajax.

Comment: In ajax response parse resultdata and then loop out

Comment: please can you review my second edit, this is the last answer i need and then i'm all good to go

Comment: Updated. Please check and add the code to your ajax success.

Comment: when i do this i get an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A". this is what i have been getting myself while trying to solve it

Comment: Its working for me. You can check here : http://jsfiddle.net/chinu7489/4cq54asv/1/

Comment: im not even getting an alert pop up. The ajax his sending because i can see the response in debugger, but for some reason i dont even get a simple alert to work now. Im confused!!